# Could not resolve host

Tags: php, curl, https

This randomly started happening again on my development computer. It works fine on the production server, so whatever. But I still need to test this here.

> Could not resolve host: (hostname); Host not found.

I know about the security vulnerabilities with these settings. But right now, I care more about getting this to work. HTTP addresses of course work fine, but those with HTTPS return no content and give an error about not being able to find the hostname. I've searched and didn't find anything useful this time.

```
function useCurl($xml,$cert,$host){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_error($ch)) {
 print "cURL error: ". curl_error($ch) ."\n<br/>";
}

 curl_close($ch);
 return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);` so that it connects to the server on the ssl enabled port?

Comment: It does that implicitly though, and this same code works on another server. But no, that didn't help. If the problem isn't the code, then where is it?

Comment: curl_error() = "Could not resolve host: (hostname); Host not found."