# Failing to connect through HTTPS and cURL at PHP

Tags: php, curl, security

I am trying to connect to an API using `cURL` and `https` and I don't get it work.

It work perfectly with `http` but when i change it to `https` in the `$url` variable, it takes more than 30 seconds to execute and finally it shows `false` as a result.

This is the function:

```
$url = 'https://api.xxxxxxx.com/api.php?user=xxxx&pass=xxxx';

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

If I debug with this:

```
debug(curl_init($url));
```

I get:

```
resource
```

Any idea which could be the cause?

Comment: Have a look here? http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: If you take a look at my code, you will see I am using what he calls " the quick fix" plus I am not getting any warning or error.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https

Comment: Have you tried connecting to another https page? Such as the ebay login page etc

Comment: @looper Again, I am already using what they all call "the quick fix"...

Comment: @Chris, connecting here, for example `https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/` it seems to work although the return value is empty. You think its a problem of the URL i am trying to connect? I can also connect to `https://google.com` and i get a 301 moved message (as expected I guess).

Comment: At a post here it is suggested to use a different port, I have no idea if it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4017643/1169669

Comment: It seems it is because the host I am trying to connect doesn't allow HTTPS connections...

Comment: Ah not so good. Tried it on a local machine?

Comment: I am executing my code from the local machine yeah.

Comment: Hmm - have you tried something other than curl?

Comment: Yeah Chris. I would say it is because the host I am trying to connect doesn't support `https` connections. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up to be that the website was trying to access didn't allow secure connections.